# Export variables from Octopus project to json file

Tags: variables, jenkins, export, octopus-deploy

Is there any way to export Octopus variables to json file, using "Command" step in Jenkins?
According to official Octopus documentation I only able to export Projects and Releases.

Is there any way to export particular variables from particular project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can not do this using [Octo.exe](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/octo.exe-command-line).

However you can still use [Octopus REST API](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/api) for your purpose.

First you have to create a [API Key](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/api/how-to-create-an-api-key), which is required to access those APIs.
Then call following API end point to get your specific project.

```
https://<your-octopus-installation>/api/projects/<project name>
```

Then response JSON contains `VariableSetId` which you should use for following request.

```
https://<your-octopus-installation>/api/variables/<VariableSetId>
```

For each of the above requests you should provide `X-Octopus-ApiKey` HTTP header with the API key as the value. Please refer [this](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/wiki) for more details.

Please note that you won't get the values of sensitive variables.

Tips: 
When you access the Octopus via browser, observe the HTTP requests it perform. That will helps you to understand, API calls that needs to be performed, to achieve your requirement.

If you are in to C# you can try [Octopus.Client](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/octopus.client)

Answer (score 1):

You can also export your Octopus Deploy configuration to JSON files using a PowerShell* module I just released:

https://github.com/DTW-DanWard/OctopusDeployUtilities

You can use Octopus Deploy Utilities (ODU) to export some or all of your data by REST API type.  It also post processes your export data, performing ID -> name look ups for you.  It also comes with a bunch of helpful utilities, like a function that gathers all data in an export into a single object so you can programmatically parse, report and even unit test your configuration.

Note: you might have difficulty exporting *just* the variable sets by themselves from your Octopus Deploy server.  Internally Octopus Deploy stores every revision of every variable set and when you call the API to pull all the variableset data, your API call is likely to time out because of all those revisions.  ODU works around that by only fetching the latest variable set data actively being used by projects and included library variable sets.

*It's written and tested in PowerShell Core so it'll run on all OSes.  It also runs well in Windows PowerShell 5.