# Download Octopus Variables from Project Library Sets

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

Can you please advise on how to download the Octopus variables set from Library in Octopus.

The Project variables can be downloaded as JSON, but for the ones in Library set, there is no such option.

Is the Octo tools the only option to export the variables set?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this script: https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/blob/master/REST/PowerShell/Variables/GetVariablesFromVariableSet.ps1

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question, please can you provide the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can get variable set from API,

Get API Call : **`{YourOctopusURL}/api/Spaces-1/variables/variableset-{LibraryVariableSetsId}`**

and **Find libraryvariablesets section**

[Reference Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449510/export-variables-from-octopus-project-to-json-file)

Let me know if you have any concern.